# NullPointer in hql insert query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I keep getting a NullPointer, when trying to retrieve a query from hql-String.
This is the line where I get my error (HibernateDataReader.java:147)

```
    Query query = currentSession.createQuery("insert into dwd_view
    (difs, dirs, temp, wdir, wvel, koordinatenid, datum, tid)
    select dwd.difs, dwd.dirs, dwd.temp, dwd.wdir, dwd.wvel, dwd.koordinatenid, dwd.datum, dwd.tid 
from dwd where dwd.koordinatenId = :coordID and dwd.datum between :start and :end")
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1192)
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1186)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:376)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:652)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2291)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.insertStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:102)
    at myproject.controller.hibernate.HibernateDataReader.execHQL(HibernateDataReader.java:147)
    at myproject.util.hibernate.WeatherCriteriaExecutor.createDWDView(WeatherCriteriaExecutor.java:144)
...
```

Other solutions recommed to include antlr, but it is already included via maven, both models are mapped and are basically identical, except different entity names and the tid column, which isn't auto increment in dwd_view.
Example for Model Class:

```
@Entity(name = "dwd") // or "dwd_view"
public class WeatherViewModel  implements HibernateModel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3506091597737302833L;

@Id
@Column(name = "tid", nullable = false, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //line missing in dwd_view
private int tid;

@Column(name = "difs")
private Double difs;

@Column(name = "dirs")
private Double dirs;

@Column(name = "temp")
private Double temp;

@Column(name = "wdir")
private Double wdir;

@Column(name = "wvel")
private Double wvel;

@Column(name = "koordinatenid")
private int koordinatenid;

@Column(name = "datum")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar datum;

//autogenerated getters and setters

}
```

Database is postgres, Hibernate Criteria Queries on the same Session Factory and/ or Tables run without any errors. Also no problems with running the query directly on the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your query is a SQL query, so you must use createSQLQuery instead of createQuery

Comment: It is a hql query based on example 4 of http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Comment: i think your select query isn't getting any data from database.

Comment: It would get data based on the restrictions. But the error isn't thrown when executing the query, but at creation.

Comment: Who is dwd_view? You have only dwd in your code

Comment: @sourApple HQL works on entity names, not on table names. You have one entity named WeatherViewModel.